# Safe to access shared resource from concurrent async tasks? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, task

I need to run multiple async methods in parallel and wait for all of them. (Task.WhenAll) Then in those methods I need to access a shared resource like a Dictionary(). Do I need it to be thread-safe?

I tried running the following two examples and both seems to imply that it is multi-threaded (interleaved messages/dates). http://rextester.com/AEH56431 http://rextester.com/YEB50034

Is there something wrong in this picture? Anybody can confirm/deny? <s>Didn't see C# Concurrency Master Stephen Cleary talk about this case specifically either.</s> EDIT: Actually Stephen talks about the threading models in his [async intro blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) which can help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        static public async Task run2() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");

            await Task.WhenAll(steps(1),steps(2),steps(3),steps(4));

            Console.WriteLine("STOP");
        }


        static public async Task steps(int i) {
            await Task.Delay(100*i);
            Console.WriteLine("step"+i+".1");
            Thread.Sleep((5-i)*300);
            Console.WriteLine("step"+i+".2");
            Thread.Sleep((5-i)*300);
            Console.WriteLine("step"+i+".3");
            Thread.Sleep((5-i)*300);
            Console.WriteLine("step"+i+".4");
        }

       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           run2().Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

and the result was:

```
START
step1.1
step2.1
step3.1
step4.1
step4.2
step3.2
step4.3   <-- multithreading? (2 isn't done)
step2.2
step1.2
step4.4
step3.3   <-- multithreading?
step2.3
step3.4
step1.3   <-- multithreading?
step2.4
step1.4
STOP
```

Then another variant:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        static public async Task run() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");

            await Task.WhenAll(steps(1),steps(2),steps(3),steps(4));

            Console.WriteLine("\nSTOP");
        }

        static public async Task steps(int i) {
            var a = new StringBuilder();

            await Task.Delay(100*i); // This is to force to run in Async mode.

            // following is a block of code with (hopefully) no "async waits". Just CPU-bound (Thread.Sleep should be blocking the thread I think?)

            a.Append("\nSTART ["+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId+"]");
            a.Append("\nstep "+i+".1 >"+DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff"));
            Thread.Sleep((5-i)*400);
            a.Append("\nstep "+i+".2 >"+DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff"));
            Thread.Sleep((5-i)*400);
            a.Append("\nstep "+i+".3 >"+DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff"));
            Thread.Sleep((5-i)*400);
            a.Append("\nstep "+i+".4 >"+DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.fff"));
            a.Append("\nSTOP");

            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        }

       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           run().Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
START

START [9]
step 4.1 >57:08.485
step 4.2 >57:08.891
step 4.3 >57:09.298
step 4.4 >57:09.704
STOP

START [8]
step 3.1 >57:08.391
step 3.2 >57:09.204
step 3.3 >57:10.017
step 3.4 >57:10.830
STOP

START [7]
step 2.1 >57:08.297
step 2.2 >57:09.501
step 2.3 >57:10.705
step 2.4 >57:11.908
STOP

START [6]
step 1.1 >57:08.203
step 1.2 >57:09.814
step 1.3 >57:11.424
step 1.4 >57:13.034
STOP

STOP
```

Comment: If you want to demonstrate something, print `CurrentThread.ManagedId`.

Comment: okidoki. I found Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId but not ManagedId. All have different ManagedThreadId

Comment: Just putting a note here that the question has materially changed. See the edit history.

Comment: Previous question was: "Can Tasks spawn from a thread run in parallel?" I tried to be more "concrete" by talking about typical multi-threading issues. To me it is the same question! Sorry for the confusion. I accepted your answer anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Your second version misses the point as all your threading is still a side effect of Task.Delay. This is simply not a good model for anything real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "steps" are able to run in parallel. An async function returns when it hits the first await on a non-completed awaitable. Here, that's `await Task.Delay(100*i);`. The continuation of a `Delay` will run on the thread pool. For that reason the delay moves the rest of the code onto the thread pool.

Without that `Delay` all of this would have been sequential (including the other sleeps).

Really, this code works kind of by coincidence. If you make all blocking async it's much clearer that it will run concurrently. Alternatively, you can insert `Task.Run` calls to *force* concurrent behavior and also to document that it's intentional.

Also note, that async IO (including `Task.Delay`) does not consume a worker thread while it is in progress. It consumes no thread at all.

Maybe it's instructional for you to remove the `Delay` call and single-step through the code. That's easy to do because everything executes on the main thread now.

Comment: Sorry, I really want to perform multiple tasks in parallel (calling multiple web services in parallel is the use case).  But then I need to know if the portion of C# code will execute concurrently (as in *multi-threading*). Or not. I will update my question to be clear.

Comment: Maybe you are not aware that await does not start threads? Maybe that's the issue. I'll wait for your edit.

Comment: async does not start threads, yes. But the code may run into another thread. Maybe there are many of those threads? (unlike in nodejs where there is only a single thread for all).
I used "Thread.Sleep()" on purpose to "hold" the thread and "see" if really they are all running simultaneously or not. If they are running simultaneously and there is no "await/Task" that would means multi-threading I assume(?). My second example uses a StringBuffer() so it is CPU bound (not I/O bound).

Comment: I don't see how the 2nd example is materially different.; Indeed, Sleep holds the thread but at the time Sleep runs you're already on the thread pool because of the delay. Remove the delay to see the difference. Delay is not magical, anything that schedules its continuation on the TP works. Try `await Task.Yield();` and `await Task.Run(() => { })` (this one is not guaranteed to work but extremely likely to work as a test).

Comment: I just notice that your question has materially changed. That's not a good way to go about it. Let's stick with the old one here. Is your question answered?

Comment: What's "CPU bound" is a vague notion. The term is quite undefined. So I don't know what to say about that. The 2 variants have the same threading behavior, though.

Comment: Sorry. Question reworded because I thought it was not getting through it seems. From your perspective it changed consistently, but from my end, it is the same. I'll accept yours since you said "These "steps" are able to run in parallel". Which concur with my tests that they are running in parallel. You also mentioned "Thread Pool" - which is something I didn't see in any C# documentation or Blog Posts about async/await programming. This is really different than NodeJS single thread model where you NEVER need to do thread-safe operations unless you explicitly do webworker/threading stuff

Comment: By "CPU bound" I meant that I didn't want it to be "I/O bound" (by the call to the Console.WriteLine) so I used a StringBuffer and gathered a date at various moments instead. Sorry for the vague notion. :)  
thanks for commenting.

Comment: The Console.WriteLine does IO but it has the same blocking and threading behavior that Sleep has. Also the same as for `a+b` (computation). No behavioral difference.

Answer (score 2):

> imply that it is multi-threaded (interleaved messages/dates)

Those would imply that it's *concurrent*. And, in fact, this line using `Task.WhenAll` is how you do asynchronous concurrency:

```
await Task.WhenAll(steps(1),steps(2),steps(3),steps(4))
```

Note that each of the steps individually are always *sequential*. So each execution of `steps` will proceed "linearly", even though it's asynchronous. This means that `1.1` will always precede `1.2`, which precedes `1.3`, etc. So all the `1.x` will be in order, `2.x` will be in order, etc. However, there are multiple concurrent executions of `steps`, and those can interleave.

Also note that this holds true whether or not there is multithreading. In this case (a Console app), there is no `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`, so every `await` is resuming on a thread pool thread. If this same code was run on a single-threaded scenario (such as a UI thread), you would see the same sequential and interleaved behavior all on the same thread.

Comment: Wow! thanks for answering! So you are saying that the fact that there is multi-threading is purely an implementation detail of the Task-ing system -- which - as you seem to say - can differ. Just to clarify: The "UI Thread" case would that be like for a Windowed App or maybe Xamarin-on-Android I suppose? But not for ASP.NET, right?

Comment: Just a little detail, the steps (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4) are *not* separated by Task.Delay() but Thread.Sleep(). This is an important distinction. So in a "UI Thread" (single thread scenario) they would never interleave. Is this correct?

Comment: @Bernard: Not an implementation detail; it's well-documented. I have an [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post that goes into detail. Yes, UI meaning GUI app, not ASP.NET.  In the UI thread scenario, the `Thread.Sleep` would block the UI thread.

Comment: Well yes and no. The semantics of where it is running can change but just looking at the source code, you cannot really "know" that.  You have to know where it is running -- hence the "implementation detail" I am talking about. I saw this article a long time ago and forgot the extend of what it contained, I should have re-read it. Thanks again for putting in all this effort for C# async programming in general!

Comment: `Thread.sleep` blocks the UI thread: I guess you mean, the difference with non-UI threads is it will not block *other tasks* since there are other threads in the pool to run them. `Thread.sleep` still blocks a thread in any case.